# Facebook comment plugin - Comments unsorted?

Tags: facebook, comments

I have developed an app on Facebook and used the Facebook comment plugin but I realised that when users comment on the page, the comments are unsorted.

Is there any way to make the comments sorted to show the latest one first?

Comment: My dear facebook always show latest comments.....

Comment: You can see an easy code for assembling the comments plugin with your web in this page: http://aplicacionesfacebookparadummies.blogspot.com/2011/10/integrar-comentarios-en-tu-web-con.html

Answer (score 0):

They aren't unsorted, but they are sorted by some sort of algorithm that is related to the number of likes, etc. As far as I can tell there is no way to control this in code.

Answer (score 0):

When you use the fb:comments tag, there is a attribute called num_posts that you can set.    If the number of comments posted is less than this, then comments are always sorted according to Facebooks "social" ordering scheme.   Once the number of comments exceeds that number, a control will appear that lets the user choose chronological ordering (both ascending and descending) or social order.    But also the user will have to hit a button to load additional comments.    You can see this in action here:

http://thinkprogress.org/politics/2011/08/25/304274/minnesota-gop-highest-bidder/#comment_link